# "The following considerations give occasion to this task."

Tags: grammar, writing-style

Is the titular sentence a grammatical and stylistically acceptable segue from the statement of the aim of an essay to an account of why the research in it is relevant?

Comment: Is the aim of your essay to demonstrate a fluent command of English, or to communicate with the reader? For example, "This paper's research is relevant for the following reasons" is much more readable.

Comment: Do the considerations cause / give rise to the task?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. You are indeed correct that a more readable sentence would be a better option. Nonetheless I would be interested to learn whether the sentence is correct, if only for the sake of my understanding of English grammar.

Comment: They do indeed, Edwin. The considerations where the reason why the task was (and ought to be) approached.

Comment: Sounds like thinking things into being. There seems to be at least one level of human agency being overlooked. OK in SF; not so good in scientific writing. 'The following considerations / Considerations of the following informed / influenced the nature of the research.'